# Excel VBA Referencing Range.Row Object Variable

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently creating an Excel workbook that uses vba to display info from a table stored in the same workbook.  I keep getting the error "Object variable or with block variable not set" when trying to run my code.  The error comes when I try to read my found line # into my rownum long value. Probably a simple fix along with other unrelated issues but any help is appreciated.

```
Dim findID As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim loc As Range
Dim foundLast As String
Dim foundFirst As String
Dim rownum As Long
Dim nameCol As Range

findID = HoursID.Value
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Totals")
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Totals")
Set nameCol = ws.Range("A2:A500")

Set loc = nameCol.Find(findID, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
rownum = loc.Row   <----------------
```

Comment: you need to test if the find is returning Nothing.  If `findID` is not found in `nameCol`, `loc` will be `Nothing` and `Nothing` does not have a row.

Comment: ^^^ It is highly recommended to specify other parameters for `Find`, especially `LookIn` and `LookAt`. See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) for more detail.